# can persistent communication be used in the for loop?

Tags: for-loop, mpi, communication, nonblocking

I want to change `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Irecv()` to persist communication to reduce time of my parallel program.

But variables in communication process will be changed during the iteration, so I alter my code in the communicaiton function as follows.

My questions are:

1. Is it persistent communication after modification？
2. If it is not persistent communication after modification,why did the time of program go down while the result of computation is correct?

   int main()
   {
   for()
   {
       //calculation process 1 will change value of q1,q2,b1,b2,b3,b4
       ....

   ```
   //communication process
   void comm()
   {
       /*if(rightBoundary==virtualWall) 
       {
           rightProcessNum=processNum+decompositionY*decompositionZ;
           for(int k=1;k<nz+1;k++)
               for(int j=1;j<ny+1;j++)
               {
                   MPI_Isend(&q1[n][k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[0]);
                   MPI_Isend(&b1   [k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,21,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[1]);
                   MPI_Isend(&b2   [k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,22,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[2]);
                   MPI_Isend(&b2   [k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,23,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[3]);
                   MPI_Isend(&b4   [k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,24,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[4]);
                   MPI_Isend(&q2[n][k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,25,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[5]);
                   MPI_Waitall(6,req1,sta1);
               }
       }

       if(leftBoundary==virtualWall) 
       {
           leftProcessNum=processNum-decompositionY*decompositionZ;
           for(int k=1;k<nz+1;k++)
               for(int j=1;j<ny+1;j++)
               {
                   MPI_Irecv(&q1[n][k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[0]);
                   MPI_Irecv(&b1   [k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,21,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[1]);
                   MPI_Irecv(&b2   [k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,22,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[2]);
                   MPI_Irecv(&b3   [k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,23,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[3]);
                   MPI_Irecv(&b4   [k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,24,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[4]);
                   MPI_Irecv(&b5[n][k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,25,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[5]);
                   MPI_Waitall(6,req2,sta2);
               }
       }*/
       if(rightBoundary==virtualWall)
       {
           rightProcessNum=processNum+decompositionY*decompositionZ;
           for(int k=1;k<nz+1;k++)
           {
               for(int j=1;j<ny+1;j++)
               {
                   MPI_Send_init(&q1[n][k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[0]);
                   MPI_Send_init(&b1   [k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,21,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[1]);
                   MPI_Send_init(&b2   [k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,22,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[2]);
                   MPI_Send_init(&b3   [k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,23,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[3]);
                   MPI_Send_init(&b4   [k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,24,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[4]);
                   MPI_Send_init(&q2[n][k][j][nx],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rightProcessNum,25,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1[5]);
                   MPI_Startall(6,req1);
               }
           }
           MPI_Waitall(6,req1,sta1);       
           MPI_Request_free(req1);
       }

       if(leftBoundary==virtualWall) 
       {
           leftProcessNum=processNum-decompositionY*decompositionZ;
           for(int k=1;k<nz+1;k++)
           {
               for(int j=1;j<ny+1;j++)
               {
                   MPI_Recv_init(&q1[n][k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[0]);
                   MPI_Recv_init(&b1   [k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,21,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[1]);
                   MPI_Recv_init(&b2   [k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,22,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[2]);
                   MPI_Recv_init(&b3   [k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,23,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[3]);
                   MPI_Recv_init(&b4   [k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,24,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[4]);
                   MPI_Recv_init(&q2[n][k][j][0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,leftProcessNum,25,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req2[5]);
                   MPI_Startall(6,req2);
               }
           }
           MPI_Waitall(6,req2,sta2);
           MPI_Request_free(req2);
       }
   }

   //calculation process 2
   ....
   ```

   }
   }
   I appreciate your time and suggestion in this problem.

Comment: your second version of the code is incorrect since you do not `MPI_Waitall()` all the requests. this is likely why the elapsed time is smaller. note you do not `MPI_Request_free()` all the requests in both versions.

Comment: if you want to run faster, you should use derived datatype(s) or manually pack/unpack data in a buffer so you can get rid of both `k` and `j` loops, and transfer large message instead of many small messages.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet : Thank you very much for your advice.I want to confirm that why the twelve requests (req1[0]~req2[5]) are not all the requests? The second version which is interrupted with "exit code:9" after the increase of iterations may be related to this.

Comment: Maybe ... this is a memory leak, and that could cause the program growing way to fat and being terminated by the OOM killer.